Visual studio 2022 doesn't recognize winrt
Visual Studio 2022 doesn't detect any "#include <winrt/(various).h" headers.
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.h>

They all give 1696 (cannot open source file) errors when I try to run the program.
I've installed the "Desktop development with C++" workload in the2022 installer, and that works fine.
But after I install Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT using NuGet, as has been directed on almost every website I've seen, it just doesn't detect winrt.
Am I missing something, or is there some abnormal problem with something deeper in my computer or Visual Studio 2022 settings? If so, where would I look to solve the problem?
I haven't added anything else to the program, so the main.cpp file is just those lines:
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.h>


Which template did you use to create C++/WinRT in Visual Studio 2022?

Firstly, does it build anyway? The NuGet package generates headers on first build. Also, one usually uses Xaml for a UWP app, which requires the UWP workload. Are you using 'WinUI on Desktop"?

I used the "Empty Project C++" template.

Thanks for your replies. I'm not sure why, but visual studio is detecting those values now. I did close and restart visual studio before which didn't work, but maybe restarting it the second time did the trick.
It's my first time working with winrt, so if you can recommend to me some tips or tutorial websites to help me get started this tool, I'd appreciate it.

@StevenBuechele Do not use the Empty Project C++ template. There are instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app

Please use the correct template to create a C++/winrt project. If similar errors occur, it is recommended to restart the visual studio or reinstall C++ (v14x) Universal Windows Platform tools or nuget package Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#visual-studio-support-for-cwinrt-xaml-the-vsix-extension-and-the-nuget-package
